# How to specify a JDK for a project in visual studio

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Hi I am using visual studio code to developp an app and to build and run the app I need JDK 1.8 so my JAVA_HOME variable is set on my jdk 1.8 but to build and run all the back end of my app I need java 1.14. So how can I configure java/visual studio code to set the folders of my back end on JDK 1.14 and folder of my front end on jdk 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Java extension needs JDK11 or recent version to support, and you have jdk14 installed, so it's required to set jdk14 as `java.home`. See [Supported Java versions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_supported-java-versions).

Then you can configure java runtime by adding the following settings in `Settings.json` or use the Java runtime configuration wizard like @OjtamOjtam suggested.

```
"java.home":"path-to-jdk14",
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-14",
            "path": "path-to-jdk14",
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk) from visual stuio code expalining how to set up multiple JDK. Basically just use runtime Configuration wizard to configure java.configuration.runtimes for each of your JDK.